# How can i find HH:MM:SS difference between two UNIX timestamps?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create some kind of timer thing. So I have some timestamp to mark finish time, and I get the current timestamp when script starts, then I just increase it by 1 every second. I need to somehow calculate difference between these two every second and display it in format of `Hours : Minutes : Seconds`.

Here is my current solution, but obviously it isn't working. `end_time` and `cur_time` are timestamps:

```
diff = end_time - cur_time;
hours_diff = Math.ceil(diff/3600)
mins_diff = Math.ceil((diff-hours_diff)/60)
secs_diff = diff - hours_diff*3600 - mins_diff*60;
```

Comment: I think you need Math.floor instead of Math.ceil.

Comment: `diff` is in seconds and `hours_diff` is in hours.. the third line should probably be something like `mins_diff = Math.floor((diff-hours_diff*3600)/60)`

Comment: 1) find the difference in seconds 2) use `Date`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start from the smaller units and work up:

```
diff = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
var secs_diff = diff % 60;
diff = Math.floor(diff / 60);
var mins_diff = diff % 60;
diff = Math.floor(diff / 60);
var hours_diff = diff % 24;
diff = Math.floor(diff / 24);
// and so on, with the next divisor being 7
// for days by week, for example.
```

At each step, you do a divide and a remainder operation. The remainder gets you the current units.  The amount you divide (and remainder) by is the number of units in the next-larger time unit.

The initial division by 1000 supposes that your timestamps are in milliseconds.  If they're in seconds, you don't need that.

You could make things a little neater by storing the divisors and the labels in an array:

```
function timeDiff( tstart, tend ) {
  var diff = Math.floor((tend - tstart) / 1000), units = [
    { d: 60, l: "seconds" },
    { d: 60, l: "minutes" },
    { d: 24, l: "hours" },
    { d: 7, l: "days" }
  ];

  var s = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < units.length; ++i) {
    s = (diff % units[i].d) + " " + units[i].l + " " + s;
    diff = Math.floor(diff / units[i].d);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: All of this `Math` stuff is completely unnecessary. A simple `Date` will do all of the work for you, and more. http://jsfiddle.net/WaZQt/. Check my answer.

Comment: @losnir yes, I've seen your answer and upvoted it :) The only advantage of this is that it gives one the flexibility to adjust the time scales the way you want. With a Date object, for example, it'd be somewhat difficult to add a "17 weeks" scale, because the Date object has no API for that time unit.

Comment: If it is going to be of any use, then that's great, else I'd personally stick with the `Date` object. By the way, you can always do `diff / 10281600` which is fine if you do not need the resolution. P.S. How would you set a scale using that function?

Comment: @losnir I think the only interesting time unit you could get with this would be the number of weeks. The number of months is going to be problematic with both my code and the Date approach; I think you'd have to do that an entirely different way. ("Number of months" is almost *inherently* a questionable time measure.)

Answer (score 5):

Use the JavaScript `Date` object to transform your timestamp into a date & time:

```
var timeDifference = end_time - cur_time;
var differenceDate = new Date(timeDifference * 1000);
var diffHours = differenceDate.getUTCHours();
var diffMinutes = differenceDate.getUTCMinutes();
var diffSeconds = differenceDate.getUTCSeconds();
```

And then to get a readable time in H:M:S format:

```
var readableDifference = diffHours + ':' + diffMinutes + ':' + diffSeconds;
```

You have to multiply by `1000` to get the difference in milliseconds (which is what the constructor of `Date` is expecting).
Unix timestamp is a representation of time passed in seconds since 1970/01/01.

A quick JSFiddle Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/WaZQt/

Comment: This will not work. It will report the time of day on the (essentially random) date that you construct from the time difference.

Comment: I have to disagree, as @lwiii pointed out, `end_time` and `cur_t` are unix timestamps, which is in seconds. By constructing a `Date` object using the difference of the two - you get the expected results.

Comment: It might work if you worked with the UTC times. For this to work, it relies on the constructed date being interpreted as some time following midnight on the first possible date.  If JavaScript time zone computations enter into it, things won't work.

Comment: @Pointy A good point (pun unintended). I have revised my answer to forcefully get time in UTC, so it will work on machines that normally does timezone conversion.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need math.floor instead of match.ceil. Anything less than 3600 seconds is not yet an hour.

You can use `modulo` (`%`) to filter out the hours from the minutes remainder (and same for the seconds).

```
hours_diff = Math.floor(diff/3600);
mins_diff = Math.floor((diff % 3600)/60)
secs_diff = diff%60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a date object with the number of milliseconds  :

```
 d = new Date (seconds * 1000);
```

Now the UTC hours, minutes and seconds correspond to your requirements

```
 console.log (d.getUTCHours () ,d.getUTCMinutes (), d.getUTCSeconds ())
```