# How can i find HH:MM:SS difference between two UNIX times

Tags: javascript

I have a Webhook listener that receives a unix timestamp value.
This timestamp is my END time.

I would like to use the current unix timestamp and compare what HH:MM:SS are left until the end time.

I was reading this post: [How can i find HH:MM:SS difference between two UNIX timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240806/how-can-i-find-hhmmss-difference-between-two-unix-timestamps)
and think it is very similar to my needs but needs a little tweaking.

Example:

```
Current time = unix now time
End time = unix time 
= How many HH:MM:SS remain before the time has ended
```

I was trying;

```js
function timeDiff(EpochTime) {
    let msec = (new Date()).valueOf() - EpochTime * 1000;
    const hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    const mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    const ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;
    return `${mm}m ${ss}s`;
}
```

Thanks
Magik

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention the language. JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk is an option:

```
awk -v etim="2021 02 08 16 27 00" '{ print strftime("%c",mktime(etim)-strftime("%s"),1) }' <<< /dev/null
```

Pass the date/time as etim and the use GNU awk's strftime and mktime functions to print the difference in the passed date and now in the locale format. Change %c to what ever format is required.